# Can multiple .vsix with VB/C# Diagnostic Analyzer/CodeFix/AutoUpdate cause performance issue?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, roslyn, vsix

I'm implementing a system that will implement code quality as part of in-house quality measures. I've structured the system in two possible ways of implementation as follows:

**Implementation 1: (Already implemented)**

1. An AutoUpdate extension (Stub)
2. C# CodeQualityPlugin (Roslyn C# Diagnostic Analyzer & Code Fix)
3. VB CodeQualityPlugin (Roslyn VB Diagnostic Analyzer & Code Fix)

The AutoUpdate feature checks for any update of itself and other CodeQuality plugins by verifying their version number. It halts update for the next 7 days once the CodeQuality plugins are updated.

*This is presently my idea of implementation, but the development is halted citing the possible performance issue related to number of extensions in this implementation and that there might be a Visual Studio limitations in its usage/performance (as mentioned by the team)*

**Implementation 2: (Suggested)**

1. C# CodeQualityPlugin (Roslyn C# Diagnostic Analyzer, Code Fix, AutoUpdate)
2. VB CodeQualityPlugin (Roslyn VB Diagnostic Analyzer, Code Fix, AutoUpdate)

In this the update functionality is individually triggered and maintains the single responsibility philosophy.

*I'm not sure if the AutoUpdate project (Which uses the menu command template) and C#/VB CodeFix/DiagnosticAnalyzer project (Roslyn Template ) can co-exist?*

**Implementation 3: (One of the opinion)**

1. CodeQualityPlugin (Roslyn C#/VB Diagnostic Analyzer, Code Fix, AutoUpdate)

*I'm not even sure if these three can co-exists in a single vsix.*

So my question what could be the performance issues in the above three scenarios, and how do we implement the plugin that we develop based on the Roslyn template into a normal menu command template extension for visual studio.

**---EDIT---**
To summarize the requirement was as follows

1. **Coexistence**: VSPackage extension (to extend shell command component of Visual Studio) and Managed Extensibility Framework/MEF extensions (to customize and extend the editor to include Roslyn DiagnosticAnalyzer/CodeFix), should coexist either in

   - Single VSIX
   - Maximum 2 VSIXs
2. **Performance**: The coexistence shouldn't affect the performance and AutoUpdate taken care by the VSPackage extension should not create redundant service calls.

Comment: These are just MEF exports. Which VSIX they're in doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @SLaks So you are saying it doesnt make any difference even if they exist as multiple VS Extension or as a single one.

Comment: @SLaks is right, which VSIX they are packaged in won't affect the performance.  Note that putting the C# and VB analyzers/fixers together can impact virtual memory, by causing extra code to load in a single language solution.

Comment: @KevinPilch-Bisson How will it impact the virtual memory when we package them together since we are filtering out the DiagnosticAnalyzers based on the language I guess `[ExportDiagnosticAnalyzer(DiagnosticId, LanguageNames.VisualBasic)]` and how will it not affect the performance when we have separate dll's stored in our `%LocalData% path`. What I meant is wont we have more dll's to load when its separately packaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Caveats of Roslyn and VSIX packaging:

*As [mentioned](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/549445) by [Srivatsn](https://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/srivatsn)*

1. Extensions that refer to both `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` and `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic` will

   - Load both the compilers even if we try to open a C# project, this is not ideal.
2. If we have to analyze the symbols `ISymbolAnalyzer`,where you are analyzing just the symbols and not the syntax nodes, then we should adopt a single language-agnostic analyzer. This means we don't have to refer any C#/VB dlls (*Even Microsoft is thinking about implementing more language-agnostic analyzer*). Include two export attributes - one for each language, these attributes tell VS to instantiate and call these analyzers when the respective language is contained in the solution.
3. Compilation as a process leaves the memory after the compilation is done, but since there is a compilation happening at almost every keystroke and if the analyzer refers to both c# and VB, it will bring both compilers into memory. Since there is a persistence characteristic,  it could be a problem if there is a large project under the solution (*This is my typical production scenario*)
4. There is a confusion whether the compiler is loaded when the respective syntax method is invoked or on instantiation of the exported analyzer (*which is again being filter through the MEF export attribute by mentioning the respective language use case*) since he also mentioned that the if a method that refers to both kind of syntax node might make the JIT compile and load the dlls.
5. Any analyzers linked to menu command would be VS specific and if they are linked to the project then it will participate in the build as well, even outside of the VS through MSBuild
6. VSIX should be able to export multiple components for extending both of those extension points.

*As [mentioned](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/06/08/persistence-facades-and-roslyn-s-red-green-trees.aspx) by [VSadov](https://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/VSadov)*

1. Persistence of the syntax tree data-structure and the need to re-do analysis at every keystroke(*delta-compilation: this is what Srivatsn's compilation means*) made them design the red-green tree method which helps in the performance of the delta-compilation.

*As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262618/can-multiple-vsix-with-vb-c-diagnostic-analyzer-codefix-autoupdate-cause-perfo/25270233#comment39362585_25262618) by [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks)*

1. MEF exports doesn't make any difference whether they are packaged in a single VSIX or not (*but it should be noted that there is a performance issue related to combining both type analyzers into a single assembly which is an MEF export*)

*As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262618/can-multiple-vsix-with-vb-c-diagnostic-analyzer-codefix-autoupdate-cause-perfo#comment39383014_25270233) by [Kevin Pilch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/678625/kevin-pilch-bisson)*

1. Although it doesn't matter where these assemblies are packaged in unless they are separate in concern when it comes to language specific references.
2. Virtual memory will be reserved if the analyzer references both the C# and VB specific Roslyn assemblies and these compiler assemblies are large
3. The performance problems being Disk loading and JIT costs (*I'm not sure how there is a JIT cost if there is no compilation and only reference in it*), but since there is an address space reserved there could be an issue in VS (*I'm not sure how that will be an issue.*)
4. What Microsoft does, according to him, is to create three projects to deal with this  (*According to Srivatsn Microsoft is still trying for language-agnostic analyzers*)

   - Shared (*No language specific binaries in it*)
   - C# specific (*+ shared libraries*)
   - VB Specific (*+ shared libraries*)
5. If no language specific binaries are referred and if the MEF exports are appropriately attributed with `ContentType` or `LanguageName` then the above issue can be solved
6. We can bundle additional assemblies into a single VSIX (*by embedding the other project in it*) and VS will load each independently

### Final Implementation:

So Finally I came to a conclusion after discussion with my team as follows

- A single VSIX implementation by embedding the following projects in it

  - Update plugin

    - Checks if update was present in the past 7 days
    - Then checks for the version number of the Plugin from server side via a JSON request
    - Then downloads the plugin from the server, stores the download date in VS settings for initial check
    - Disables the previous plugin
    - Uninstalls the previous plugin
    - Installs the new plugin
    - This functionality is triggered when

      - The VS loads
      - Manual menu command (which should override the download date check)
  - C# plugin

    - Implements and refers only rules for C#
  - VB Plugin

    - Implements and refers only rules for VB

Answer (score 2):

No.

The only real "performance problem" you can have is putting the C# and VB ones in the same assembly (note, not VSIX), which would mean when we have to load one we load the others.

From the perspective of MEF, we just get a list of exports back: we don't know which VSIXes they're from, and it's hard to figure out if even if we wanted to. So which VSIX you put stuff in doesn't matter at all: divide them up based upon what makes sense for your users.

Comment: And yes, this adds no new information than what everybody said in comments. But somebody has to officially "answer" it! :-)

Comment: If the shared assembly references both the C# and VB specific Roslyn assemblies, it can cause both sets to get loaded, and have virtual memory reserved for the code in them.  In the case of the compiler assemblies, that can be fairly large.  NOTE that it doesn't directly affect performance much (apart from disk loading and JIT costs), but the address space will be reserved, which can be an issue in VS.

Comment: @KevinPilch-Bisson Suppose I completely change my implementation. Like now I'm using two separate projects that are packaged under the same VSIX. Since this implementation infers that there are separate dlls for C# and VB, I guess this "performance issue" will stand invalid.

Comment: One VSIX is fine.  What we do to prevent the language specific assemblies from loading when they shouldn't is create three projects - shared, c# specific, and VB specific.  Then we make sure that shared has no references to any language specific Roslyn binaries, C# references the C# and shared Roslyn assemblies, and VB references the VB and Shared Roslyn binaries.  This works as long as nothing in your shared library causes the language specific binaries to load through MEF, and as long as your MEF exports are appropriately attributed with ContentType or LanguageName.

Comment: @KevinPilch-Bisson This is perfect! but what if I had to include another plugin implementation along with this (Update command to update the analyzer extension) together in a single VSIX. In your opinion is there any chances of failed coexistence, would there be any MEF load time exception. Like I'm using OLE Command and Interop for other fact checks before the update.

Comment: Bundling additional assemblies into the VSIX shouldn't cause an issue.  VS still loads each assembly independently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59244/discussion-between-jerric-lyns-john-and-kevin-pilch-bisson).